# How to detect in what collection is failing Missing or insufficient permissions on Firebase

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have some functions which modify many documents and I get this error
`FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`
It is posible to detect in what collection is failing my rules without comment one by one my operations to firebase?

I tried to find in the firebase error returned, but I couldnt find the collection here:

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
window.console.error @ next-dev.js:24
overrideMethod @ console.js:213
_callee$ @ notebook.tsx:909
tryCatch @ runtime.js:45
invoke @ runtime.js:274
prototype.<computed> @ runtime.js:97
asyncGeneratorStep @ _async_to_generator.mjs:3
_throw @ _async_to_generator.mjs:29
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ _async_to_generator.mjs:13
_next @ _async_to_generator.mjs:25
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ _async_to_generator.mjs:13
_next @ _async_to_generator.mjs:25
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ _async_to_generator.mjs:13
_next @ _async_to_generator.mjs:25
eval @ _async_to_generator.mjs:32
eval @ _async_to_generator.mjs:21
eval @ notebook.tsx:783
eval @ useMemoizedCallback.ts:10
eval @ notebook.tsx:4903
detectTriggerTutorial @ notebook.tsx:5203
eval @ notebook.tsx:5895
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24926
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24891
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24878
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24866
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26935
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26117
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
eval @ react-dom.development.js:25651
Show 1 more frame
```

Comment: You might want to link up your Firebase with Cloud logging, if you haven't here is the [documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9748636?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article). This might be the possible way to check the collection that causes the error. 

You can run this query `protoPayload.status.message="PERMISSION_DENIED"` to identify which logs that provided the "PERMISSION_DENIED".

Comment: Try to add the name of the collection in front of the error message.